# Bluetooth LE: как ждать, когда включится устройство

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Имеется устройство, которое может включаться, запрашивать соединение и передавать данные. Работает с Bluetooth LE.

Что надо сделать в программе, чтобы она ждала этого включения и устанавливала соединение?

Вот варианты, которые мне пришли в голову, но я не знаю, какой правильный:

1. Запускать каждые 3-5 секунд сканер, чтобы проверял, нет ли сигнала от нужного устройства. Но это, как мне кажется, как-то не согласуется с концепцией LE.
2. Запустить сканер и не останавливать, пока не появится устройство. Но во всех примерах, которые мне попадались, сканер запускают на несколько секунд и останавливают. И тоже вроде не согласуется с концепцией.
3. Какой-то системный сервис шлет сообщение, если включается устройство. Только откуда он тогда знает, какое именно устройство интересует приложение? И как его подключить?
4. Создать свой сервис, который будет каким-то образом отслеживать появление сигнала и слать сообщения. Но как такой сервис реализовать?

Не нашла нормального описания. Пример на Develop посмотрела, но все равно не поняла. Пожалуйста помогите, никак не могу разобраться.

Может кто-то подскажет, где прочитать (лучше на русском)?

Comment: А ваше устройство само не может приконнектиться? Работать как хост? Если не может, то придется периодически, либо все время сканировать.

Comment: Нет, само не может.

Comment: значит в любом случае придется сканировать.